# Delphi Exponent Calculator

Tags: lazarus

Sorry for my English, as I am from Germany.

I built a program: http://i.epvpimg.com/I0xie.png

And I want an exponent calculator (I am learning for test in school), but I have a problem...

If I do the number "Zahl" (meaning "number" in German). For example: `Number= "2"`, then I do `exponent = "1"`.

Normally I should get the result `2` but I am  getting a `4`, why?

What is the problem?

Here is my Code:

```
unit unit_oberflaeche;

{$mode objfpc}{$H+}

interface

uses
  Classes, SysUtils, FileUtil, Forms, Controls, Graphics, Dialogs, StdCtrls,
  ExtCtrls, unit_inhalt;

type

  { TForm1 }

  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Button1: TButton;
    Edit1: TEdit;
    Edit2: TEdit;
    Label1: TLabel;
    Label2: TLabel;
    Panel1: TPanel;
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);

  private
    { private declarations }
  public
    { public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;
  rechner: Texponentrechner;

implementation

{$R *.lfm}

{ TForm1 }


procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
    rechner := Texponentrechner.Create;
end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
VAR i, LVexponent, LVzahl, result: INTEGER;
     BEGIN
     LVexponent := StrToInt(Edit2.Text);
     LVzahl     := StrToInt(Edit1.Text);
     rechner.set_exponent(LVexponent);
     rechner.set_zahl(LVzahl);
         FOR i := 1 TO LVexponent DO
             BEGIN
               result := result * LVzahl

             end;
         //result := LVzahl;
     Panel1.Caption := IntToStr(result);
     end;

end.
```

And here is the other part:

```
unit unit_inhalt;

{$mode objfpc}{$H+}

interface

uses
  Classes, SysUtils;


TYPE
  Texponentrechner = class
  private
    { private declarations }
    Fexponent : INTEGER;
    Fzahl     : INTEGER;

  public
    { public declarations }

    procedure set_exponent   (WPexponent:INTEGER);
    procedure set_zahl       (WPzahl:INTEGER);

    function  berechne_betrag():INTEGER;
    end;




implementation

procedure Texponentrechner.set_exponent(WPexponent:INTEGER);
 BEGIN
      Fexponent := WPexponent;
end;

procedure Texponentrechner.set_zahl(WPzahl:INTEGER);
 BEGIN
      Fzahl := WPzahl;
 end;

function Texponentrechner.berechne_betrag():INTEGER;
 BEGIN
      result := Fzahl * Fzahl;
 end;

end.
```

Comment: `result` variable is not initialized (regularly it is initialized as 0 by compiler but you can not sure); Do not name variables etc in some language except of English: may be your program will use somehow who does not understand German, but almost all programmers understand English. Do you mean "Exponent" is e^n (e = 2.71828)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that your exponent calculation has to be done in `Texponentrechner` class. First, your calculation there is wrong because it returns your number multiplied by itself, and second you are never calling that function in the first place.

So your `berechne_betrag` function should look like this:

```
function Texponentrechner.berechne_betrag(): integer;
var i: integer;
begin
  Result := 1;
  for i := 1 to Fexponent do
    Result := Result * Fzahl;
end;
```

Then you should actually call that function to get the result

```
rechner.set_exponent(LVexponent);
rechner.set_zahl(LVzahl);
result := rechner.berechne_betrag;
Panel1.Caption := IntToStr(result);
```

Also you are creating `rechner` object instance in `FormCreate`, but you are never releasing it and thus you are creating memory leak. You should call `rechner.Free` when you are finished using object. Since you have made it global var you create in `FormCreate`, proper place to release it will be in `FormDestroy`

But even better practice would be to make it local to `Button1Click` method.

```
...
type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Button1: TButton;
    Edit1: TEdit;
    Edit2: TEdit;
    Label1: TLabel;
    Label2: TLabel;
    Panel1: TPanel;
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.lfm}

{ TForm1 }

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var 
  LVexponent, LVzahl, result: integer;
  rechner: Texponentrechner;
begin
  rechner := Texponentrechner.Create;
  try
    LVexponent := StrToInt(Edit2.Text);
    LVzahl     := StrToInt(Edit1.Text);
    rechner.set_exponent(LVexponent);
    rechner.set_zahl(LVzahl);
    result := rechner.berechne_betrag;
    Panel1.Caption := IntToStr(result);
  finally
    rechner.Free;
  end;
end;

end.
```